# Predicting the correct graph for the E.M.F induced

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

To be honest, this is a homework question. A screenshot of this question is given below.

[image]

NOTE: *The correct word for the one that I encircle with blue colour should be "rotates"*

**My argument towards this question**

Initially there is no induced E.M.F on the loop. But when it enters to the magnetic field which ultimately leads to have an induced E.M.F . And when time passes  E.M.F induced on the loop should be increased , because as the time pass , the area of the loop in space containing magnetic field increase.And after that it should comes to it's initial state and follow the same procedure   again and again .

So the answer I choose was 3 . But I don't know whether my argument and my answer are correct, which leads my mind to ask this question in this great site.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right. Think about the rate at which the area increases as the semicircle goes around. However much the area grows, that is how the flux grows - and that tells you what the EMF is.

So if the rate of growing / shrinking is sinusoidal, then (3) is the right answer. But what is the actual rate?

You might want to do a bit of geometry to write the area as a function of time... it's not hard. See for example this diagram:

[image]

At a given time, the area of the loop that is inside the magnetic field is $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\pi r^2$. If the loop is rotating at a constant velocity $\omega$, then some time $\Delta t$ later the angle $\theta$ will have increased by $d\theta=\omega \Delta t$. This increase leads to a change in flux 
$$\Delta \Phi = B \cdot dA = B \frac{\omega\; \Delta t}{2\pi} \pi r^2$$

In other words, while the area of the loop covering the magnetic field is growing,

$$\frac{d\Phi}{dt} = \frac{B\omega r^2}{2}$$

and the e.m.f. induced is constant (all the terms on the right hand side are constant).

Once the loop has fully covered the magnetic field and starts to "leave", you can do the same analysis at the tail end - and see that the area gets smaller at a constant rate. This means that the change in flux through the loop will now be negative:

$$\frac{d\Phi}{dt} = -\frac{B\omega r^2}{2}$$

It is the same size as before, but the opposite magnitude. We expect a square wave - answer #2. The positions of the loop as a function of time will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you quite sure about your choice. Because in the marking scheme it's given as 2!

Comment: Indeed - the rate of change is NOT sinusoidal. I was trying not to give it all away - that is the policy with homework questions... Hence I said "IF the rate is sinusoidal, THEN ..." I also said "you are ALMOST right" - correct reasoning, but it did not lead you to the right conclusion because you did not think hard enough about the exact shape.

Comment: Area is given (Pi)r^2 whole thing divide by 2. So how can I proceeed with that?

Comment: When the loop is rotated by an angle $\theta$, the part that "sees" magnetic field is $\frac{\theta}{\pi}\pi R^2$. So the area grows linearly with $\theta$ (and then decreases linearly once the overlap area has reached its peak). Constant rate of change = flat top on the emf curve. Half the time positive (growing area), half the time negative (shrinking area).

Comment: When does the peak position  occur, is it when whole loop is inside the B field?

Comment: The top is flat so the "peak" lasts as long as the area is growing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25007/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-floris).

Comment: But then why does it kept  **constant** for some time ?

Comment: The rate at which the area grows is constant just like the area swept by the second hand of a clock grows linearly with time (it "eats" 1/60th of the circle every second)

Comment: Aha , I get it now. The changing rate is constant(like second-hand of the clock). So one thing to confirm, when does the  that rate become negetive.?

Comment: It becomes negative when the full disk covers the magnetic field and then starts "leaving" the field (the area covered gets smaller again). If you like the "leading edge" sweeps a positive area and the "trailing edge" sweeps a negative area.

Comment: It means after  full disk covers, rate of E.M.F change oppose with the same magnitude. So is it possible to  come to a  conclusion as ,for the first rotation it is positive  ,second it's negative, like- wise for odd numbers it's positive  while for even numbers it's negative

Comment: For the first HALF rotation it is positive (area increasing), etc...

Comment: Then for second half ?

Comment: It is negative... Thus square wave shape and answer (2).

Comment: Important points that I have arrived by your help is,  the rate of change of E.M.F is constant because the rate of area that goes into the B field is constant. So we can neglect all other answers except (2) and (4)  . But after that I am confused with designating positive and negative sign  of the rate .

Comment: I have elaborated on all these points in the answer.

Comment: @ Floris : Is this  correct ,"When  the **AREA**  of the loop decrease inside the  B , changing E.M.F becomes negative value " ?

Comment: Yes that is correct - as long as you chose your conventions so that positive corresponds to the area increasing (you get to pick what you consider "up" and "down" - the point is that the emf will change direction when the area goes from "growing" to "shrinking")

Comment: @ Do you like to move this into a chat ?